# Logrotate Says It Rotated Logs, But Didn't

Tags: cron, logrotate

OK, here's my situation.  I'm trying to use logrotate to rotate VNC logs for a specific user on an hourly basis.  Based on the feedback I get when I run the utility, the log rotation goes off, but when I look at the directory involved, nothing has actually changed.

System is Ubuntu 18.02 LTS. I'm doing all administration remotely through SSH.

Before I run my job, the /home/guest/.vnc directory looks like this:

```
localadmin@xfce-kiosk-production-working:/etc$ sudo ls -l /home/guest/.vnc
total 120
-rw------- 1 guest guest      8 Oct 13 05:33 passwd
-rw-rw-r-- 1 guest guest 112995 Feb  1 14:56 xfce-kiosk-production-working:1.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 guest guest    274 Oct 13 05:39 xstartup
```

I invoke my script in `cron.hourly` like so:

```
sudo /etc/cron.hourly/logrotate
bash: guest: No such file or directory
reading config file /etc/logrotate.hourly.conf
Reading state from file: /var/lib/logrotate/status
Allocating hash table for state file, size 64 entries
Creating new state
["Creating new state" x28 deleted]

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /home/guest/.vnc/xfce-kiosk-production-working:1.log  102400 bytes (4 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /home/guest/.vnc/xfce-kiosk-production-working:1.log
Creating new state
  Now: 2021-02-01 14:58
  Last rotated at 2021-02-01 14:00
  log needs rotating
rotating log /home/guest/.vnc/xfce-kiosk-production-working:1.log, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20210201'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed
renaming /home/guest/.vnc/xfce-kiosk-production-working:1.log to /home/guest/.vnc/xfce-kiosk-production-working:1.log-20210201
creating new /home/guest/.vnc/xfce-kiosk-production-working:1.log mode = 0664 uid = 1001 gid = 1001
```

But when I go back to the directory:

```
localadmin@xfce-kiosk-production-working:/etc$ sudo ls -l /home/guest/.vnc
total 120
-rw------- 1 guest guest      8 Oct 13 05:33 passwd
-rw-rw-r-- 1 guest guest 112995 Feb  1 14:56 xfce-kiosk-production-working:1.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 guest guest    274 Oct 13 05:39 xstartup
```

My `/etc/cron.hourly/logrotate` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
su guest guest

/usr/sbin/logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.hourly.conf
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
        /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT hourly job exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

and my `/etc/logrotate/hourly.conf` file:

```
/home/guest/.vnc/xfce-kiosk-production-working:1.log {
        size 100k
        create 664 guest guest
        rotate 4
        missingok
        dateext
}
```

Thanks in advance.  I'm new to logrotate, so I'm still trying to make sense of things here.

**EDIT**

I found out the problem was a permissions issue- the `su guest guest` command in the script was bringing up a new shell, not causing the rest of the script to be executed as guest, and the default `logrotate` user didn't have permission to access the logs in question.

I ended up deleting the `/etc/cron.hourly/logrotate` script and instead putting the following into `/etc/crontab`:

`0 * * * * root logrotate -f /etc/logrotate/hourly.conf`

That causes the logrotate job to execute every hour, and since it runs as root there are no permission issues.

Thanks to everyone who contacted me with suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Jeff,

I think you shall remove `su guest guest` from the script. I doubt it is the root cause, but it can help, because:

- this job is supposed to be run by root anyway (you can see it creates the new file as expected for: `uid = 1001 gid = 1001` - which I guess is `guest`)
- su with 2 parameters will error out (we can see `bash: guest: No such file or directory`)
- if su is successful it will stop the script until the su command is finished which is not intended (`sudo -u guest` makes the trick, but I think you don't need it here)

Other than that I can't spot any issue and it looks strange that there is no change after the run of the script, even if we can see what the rotator is doing (or trying to do).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I ended up with a different solution, which I will post momentarily, but you're right that `su guest guest` was not the way to go.